# Twitter Bootstrap Button Text Word Wrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

For the life of me I am unable to get these twitter bootstrap buttons to text wrap onto multiple lines, they appearing like so.

I cannot post images, so this is what it is doing...

[This is the bu] tton text

I would like it to appear like

[This is the ]

[button text ]

```
<div class="col-lg-3"> <!-- FIRST COL -->
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body"> 
    <h4>Posted on</h4>
    <p>22nd September 2013</p>
    <h4>Tags</h4>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs col-lg-12" style="margin-bottom:4px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</a>
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs col-lg-12" style="margin-bottom:4px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</a>
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs col-lg-12" style="margin-bottom:4px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</a>
           </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit. I have tried adding `word-wrap:break-word;` but it is not making any difference.

Edit. JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TTKtb/ - You will need it expand the right column so the panels sit next to one another.

Comment: Can u create jsfiddle or some test for that ??

Comment: Why don't you insert `<br>` where you want to insert line break?

Comment: Not viable as the contents of the buttons will vary as loaded from a database.

Comment: The other way http://jsfiddle.net/TTKtb/4/

Comment: If you insert a <br> at the point you want your text to wrap you get a line break and the text wraps. I know this is not a solution when you have a lot of text but when you have three or four words that you want to wrap this might help !

Answer (score 378, accepted):

Try this: add **white-space: normal;** to the style definition of the Bootstrap Button or you can replace the code you displayed with the one below

```
<div class="col-lg-3"> <!-- FIRST COL -->
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body"> 
    <h4>Posted on</h4>
    <p>22nd September 2013</p>
    <h4>Tags</h4>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs col-lg-12" style="margin-bottom:4px;white-space: normal;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</a>
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs col-lg-12" style="margin-bottom:4px;white-space: normal;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</a>
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs col-lg-12" style="margin-bottom:4px;white-space: normal;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</a>
           </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have updated your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TTKtb/2/) to show how it comes out.

Comment: Ahh, wow. Just looked it up. Didn't even know that CSS code existed. Thanks for your help! Spent hours trying to work this one out.

Comment: @user2063032 I think this guy can best explain white-space [link](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-white-space/).

Comment: No worries, I learn something each day from stackoverflow. Also you'll notice that the white-space property works well if the element i.e. the button is of a specified width.

Comment: I am having this issue but with the panel title, how it an be fixed?? ideas

Comment: @victorsosa Kindly provide a fiddle with the code in question plus specify the element you're trying to manipulate

Answer (score 75):

You can simply add this class.

```
.btn {
    white-space:normal !important;
    word-wrap: break-word; 
}
```

Comment: i also needed ```word-break: normal``` to override the value set by bootstrap. But then it worked a charm!

Answer (score 9):

FWIW, in Boostrap 4.4, you can add `.text-wrap` style to things like buttons:

```html
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary text-wrap">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</a>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/text/#text-wrapping-and-overflow

Answer (score 2):

You can add these style's and it works just as expected.

```
.btn {
    white-space:normal !important; 
    word-wrap: break-word; 
    word-break: normal;
}
```

Comment: Using inline styles would only allow you to fix this for that one button. Add it to a class so you can use it throughout your project. Using a col definition in a class on an anchor would be seen as bad practice whilst using Bootstrap.