# Bootstrap 4 - word wrap text without change the height

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Coming from: [Twitter Bootstrap Button Text Word Wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18996202/twitter-bootstrap-button-text-word-wrap)

How can I set the word wrap of a text inside a button in bootstrap 4, without change the height or with all buttons with the same height? For example:

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm">
    <button id="1" type="button" class="btn spectral btn-secondary btn-block cbb ">Opciones Generales</button>
    </div>

       <div class="col-sm">
    <button id="2" type="button" class="btn spectral btn-secondary btn-block cbb">1</button>
    </div>


       <div class="col-sm">
    <button id="4" type="button" class="btn spectral btn-secondary  btn-block cbb">2</button>
    </div>

        <div class="col-sm">
    <button id="5" type="button" class="btn spectral btn-secondary  btn-block cbb ">3</button>
    </div>

       <div class="col-sm">
    <button id="6" type="button" class="btn spectral btn-secondary btn-block cbb">Cambio de Nacionalidad</button>
    </div>

    </div><br />


            <div class="row">

           <div class="col-sm">
    <button id="7" type="button" class="btn spectral btn-secondary  btn-block cbb">4</button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm">
    <button id="9" type="button" class="btn spectral btn-secondary  btn-block cbb ">5</button>
    </div>


       <div class="col-sm">
    <button id="11" type="button" class="btn spectral btn-secondary  btn-block cbb">6</button>
    </div>

       <div class="col-sm">
    <button id="12" type="button" class="btn spectral btn-secondary  btn-block cbb">7</button>
    </div>

           <div class="col-sm">
    <button id="10" type="button" class="btn spectral btn-danger  btn-block cbb">Crear Item</button>
    </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

returns this:
[image]

with the answer from that question (that is duplicated everywhere but the answer is the same everywhere)

```
.btn{
    white-space:normal !important;
    word-wrap: break-word; 
}
```

but the expected result is that "Cambio de Nacionalidad" being aligned.

Comment: set a fixed height or a max-height

Comment: @TemaniAfif a fixed height. But when I fix the height, its looks worse!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using BS 4 the `col-*` are flex items stretched by default so simply use `height:100%` on the button

```css
.btn {
 height:100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm">
    <button id="1" type="button" class="btn spectral btn-secondary btn-block cbb ">Opciones Generales</button>
    </div>

       <div class="col-sm">
    <button id="2" type="button" class="btn spectral btn-secondary btn-block cbb">1</button>
    </div>


       <div class="col-sm">
    <button id="4" type="button" class="btn spectral btn-secondary  btn-block cbb">2</button>
    </div>

        <div class="col-sm">
    <button id="5" type="button" class="btn spectral btn-secondary  btn-block cbb ">3</button>
    </div>

       <div class="col-sm">
    <button id="6" type="button" class="btn spectral btn-secondary btn-block cbb">Cambio de Nacionalidad</button>
    </div>

    </div><br />


            <div class="row">

           <div class="col-sm">
    <button id="7" type="button" class="btn spectral btn-secondary  btn-block cbb">4</button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm">
    <button id="9" type="button" class="btn spectral btn-secondary  btn-block cbb ">5</button>
    </div>


       <div class="col-sm">
    <button id="11" type="button" class="btn spectral btn-secondary  btn-block cbb">6</button>
    </div>

       <div class="col-sm">
    <button id="12" type="button" class="btn spectral btn-secondary  btn-block cbb">7</button>
    </div>

           <div class="col-sm">
    <button id="10" type="button" class="btn spectral btn-danger  btn-block cbb">Crear Item</button>
    </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that's nice! but now the above row has more height than the lower one

Comment: @MacGyver yes because there is no relation between them, each one is directed by its content