# How can I make button width to follow the most larger width button based on text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, laravel

How can I make all my button to follow the width of a larger width based on text?

The button produce dynamically and the text will be based on data on database. then I want them to have the same size on UI.

Is this possible? If it is. how?

**Here's my button:**

```
@foreach($buttons as $button)
 <button class="btn col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 text-center btn-button button{{$button->parent_id}} hide" type="button" onclick="buttonFunction('button{{$button->id}}'"  style="background-color: #69C1DA;">
  <input type="radio" class="hide" name="type" value="{{$button->id}}" id="button{{$button->id}}">
  <span>{{$button->name}}</span>
 </button>
@endforeach
```

**Here's the UI of my button**

[image]

as you can see the text is not fitted. I can make the button bigger than what is it now but I don't know when a word will be on database that is large enough for it to be not fit again.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try css property ```white-space: normal;``` to your button class??

Comment: @ManirajMurugan what is the use of that?

Comment: It will make the text to fit into the width of the button..

Comment: @ManirajMurugan its make my specific button to have another height which is not good for me too

Comment: Are you making any default width to those buttons??

Comment: as of now its just bootstrap col class. I want it to have a dynamic width too that based on the largest text. I dont know if its possible using js

Comment: You are already making ```col-md-3``` in bootstrap so how it will be possible to extend the width as it is well fit with the grid system of 12 col split up??

Comment: I want the all of the button to have the same width. If its possible to get the width of button that has larger text then I will change the col-md-3

Comment: Check whether this one helps you https://stackoverflow.com/a/54621974/7785337 ??

Comment: I dont think I want to change the height of my button. I dont really like large button.

Comment: Then I would suggest don't make the col num split up, just give it ```col```, https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/OJVMjBb .. This will make everything in auto..

Comment: `col` didn't work for me too. anyway thank you @ManirajMurugan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it was me - I would forget trying to use the boostrap columns and simply style the width with css.

This can be done in plain javascript (esp using the document.querySelectorAll() selector - but since you are using jquery - here is the approach -

iterate over the buttons and find the max-width by comparing each buttons width to a max-width and if it is greater than maxwidth  - setting that width as the max-width.

Then set all the buttons to the maxWidth and voila - all buttons are the same width as the button with the longest text.

Note that i removed some of your code just for this snippet - and also moved the style into the css block - it is always better to use exteranl css than inline for each button. If you want different astyles for different buttons -apply different classes with the different styling.

```js
let maxWidth = 0;

$('.btn').each(function(){
 const width = parseFloat($(this).css('width'));
 if(width > maxWidth) {maxWidth = width}
})

$('.btn').css('width', maxWidth +'px');
```

```css
.btn {
  background-color: #69C1DA;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn text-center btn-button button{{$button->parent_id}} hide" type="button">

  <span>text</span>
 </button>
  <button class="btn text-center btn-button button{{$button->parent_id}} hide" type="button">
  <span>longer text</span>
 </button>
  <button class="btn text-center btn-button button{{$button->parent_id}} hide" type="button" onclick="buttonFunction('button{{$button->id}}'">
  <span> very very long text</span>
 </button>
   <button class="btn text-center btn-button button{{$button->parent_id}} hide" type="button">
  <span>short text</span>
 </button>
```

Comment: this didn't work for me. my button didn't have any width. I will edit my answer and see the photo

Comment: and i was using inline css because that's just for two button. but i will take that in consideration. and on what I tried i also remove all my col bootstrap

Comment: Oh wait this works. I forgot to add that my button in default are hiding so I guess when my web loads it will read the default width are 0 because they're hide. I just put your code when I need to show the button. Thanks a lot @gavgrif

Comment: you are welcome - happy to help. Good luck with your coding

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is an easy way to do this using *jQuery* with minimal code.

You can modify this solution to [get the largest button width and apply that width to all](https://ardalis.com/use-jquery-to-format-buttons-same-width).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $.fn.widest = function() {
    return this.length ? this.width(Math.max.apply(Math, this.map(function() { 
        return $(this).width();
    }))) : this;
 };
  
    $('.buttons').widest();
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="buttons" >One</button>
<button class="buttons" >Twooooo</button>
<button class="buttons" >Three Four Five Six Seven Eight</button>
```

ps: in the website, they provided a solution which involves click to get the width, so modify it like my code, where you remove the *click function* and call that code in the *ready function*.

This will ensure that your buttons will always take the largest button width value and apply that to all other buttons.

Comment: Add more content to the button value and you can see that the other buttons will automatically take the new largest width :)

Answer (score 2):

Answer is already here , but i add this one for info about  using `grid` and custom properties.

element can wrap on few rows but will all be the same width, demo below .

```js
var bigW = '0';
for (let e of document.querySelectorAll('.btn')) {
  elW = e.offsetWidth;
  if (elW > bigW) {
    bigW = elW;
  }
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--myW", bigW + 'px');// update column's width //
}
```

```css
div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, var(--myW)); /* custom properie here to size the columns */
  justify-content: center;/* center them for a better visual*/
}

button {
  white-space: nowrap;  /* we need this */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="btn">some more text </button>
  <button class="btn">text </button>
  <button class="btn">some bits of text </button>
  <button class="btn">Lorem Ipsum</button>
  <button class="btn">some loooooonnnng text </button>
  <button class="btn">some some text </button>
  <button class="btn">some text </button>
  <button class="btn">some text </button>
  <button class="btn">some text </button>
  <button class="btn">some text </button>
  <button class="btn">some text </button>
  <button class="btn">some text </button>
  <button class="btn">some text </button>
  <button class="btn">some text </button>
  <button class="btn">some text </button>
  <button class="btn">some text </button>
</div>
```

Here is a pen to fork or play with  https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/GRJovXZ

DISCLAIMER : requires a browsers that supports **CSS Grid Layout** and **custom properties / CSS variables** (--*:value)

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*
>
> Property names that are prefixed with `--`, like `--example-name`, represent custom properties that contain a value that can be used in other declarations using the `var()` function.

---

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout
>
> CSS Grid Layout excels at dividing a page into major regions or defining the relationship in terms of size, position, and layer, between parts of a control built from HTML primitives.

support information can be find out at http://caniuse.com

Answer (score 1):

As I can see, you'll need to set the width after all the content of the buttons is updated. So, you can check the largest width with Javascript and change the button width property according to it.

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
let maxWidth = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
{
  // You need to check the maximum value of all
  if (maxWidth < buttons[i].offsetWidth) maxWidth = buttons[i].offsetWidth;
}

for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
{
  // You set the width to the max plus the padding left and right
  buttons[i].style.width = maxWidth + 40 + 'px';
}

// This was the maximum width
document.querySelector('p').innerHTML = maxWidth + 40 + 'px';
```

```css
.btn
{
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid blueviolet;
  color: white;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  margin: 1vmin 2vmin;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}
.btn:hover
{
  color: blueviolet;
  background-color: transparent;
 }
```

```html
<button class='btn'>
  This is a button
</button>
<button class='btn'>
  Ok, you shoud click this!
</button>
<button class='btn'>
  Click here!
</button>
<button class='btn'>
  Learn more
</button>
<button class='btn'>
  Come here, buddy!
</button>
<button class='btn'>
  What a button
</button>
<p>
</p>
```